# Universal image loader share images with other apps

Tags: android, image, android-intent, sharing, universal-image-loader

I am using Universal Image Loader to show images in my app. There is image sharing functionality to share images with other apps.

**Right now I'm doing:**

```
ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
File file = imageLoader.getDiskCache().get(url);
if (file != null) {
   Util.shareImage(getActivity(), file);
}

public static void shareImage(Context context, File pictureFile) {
    Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(pictureFile.getAbsolutePath());
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
    shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
    //shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
    shareIntent.setType("image/*");
    context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share"));
}
```

Below are the values for variables.

[image]

**Not sure why it's not working?**

Answer (score 0):

try "static" give away

```
public void shareImage(Context context, File pictureFile) {
 Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(pictureFile.getAbsolutePath());
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
    shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was missing this permission which seems to be required to be able to share images

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```